# Get Subdirectories using Swift

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

I'm trying to get ONLY subdirectories. Here's my data structure.

root/

- a/

  - 1.txt
  - 2.txt
- b/

  - 3.txt
  - 4.txt

I want to get directories in a specific folder(root). I use enumerator in root file path:

```
let enumerator = NSFileManager.defaultManager().enumeratorAtPath(filePath)
for element in enumerator! {
   print(element)
}
```

However, It will iterate every files in root. How can I get just subdirectories (a&b) ?

Comment: It is unclear what  you are asking. Are you trying to list only the directories located in a specific folder?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to get directories in a specific folder

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is no need to use a deep enumeration. Just get contentsOfDirectoryAtURL and filter the urls returned which are directories.

**Xcode 11.4• Swift 5.2**

```
extension URL {
    func subDirectories() throws -> [URL] {
        // @available(macOS 10.11, iOS 9.0, *)
        guard hasDirectoryPath else { return [] }
        return try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: self, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [.skipsHiddenFiles]).filter(\.hasDirectoryPath)
    }
}
```

---

usage:

```
 do {
    let documentsDirectory =  try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    let url = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("pictures", isDirectory: true)
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path) {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: url, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
    }
    let subDirs = try documentsDirectory.subDirectories()
    print("sub directories", subDirs)
    subDirs.forEach { print($0.lastPathComponent) }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```