# Get only url of files without directories

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

How can I get URL of the files in a URL?

I tried these:

```
directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: aURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: [URLResourceKey.isRegularFileKey], options: [])
```

and

```
...contentsOfDirectory(at: aURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: []).filter{ $0.isFileURL })
```

Both result is equal to

```
...contentsOfDirectory(at: aURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
```

that return the list of files and folders and it get the list without any filter and option.

Also I tried to get only directories by `URLResourceKey.isDirectoryKey`, but it didn't work.

How can I get the URL of files without directories?

Comment: What do you mean without filter? There is no skip directories or skip regular files options.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34389573/2303865 You can use the same approach to filter the files using isRegularFileKey

Comment: Yes, that's for an URL and didn't work for me.

Comment: Is it iOS or MacOS? If it is MacOS, are you searching a folder thats is being automatically backup by  iCloud (like documents or desktop) or is it a regular folder?

Comment: Note that isFileURL returns true for Directories also

Comment: It's iOS app. @vadian answer works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`includingPropertiesForKeys` does retrieve the information for the specified keys from the url while traversing the directory for performance reasons, it's not a filter criterium.

You have to `filter` the result explicitly either by the `isDirectory` value

```
let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: aURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: [.isDirectoryKey])
let filesOnly = directoryContents.filter { (url) -> Bool in
    do {
        let resourceValues = try url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.isDirectoryKey])
        return !resourceValues.isDirectory!
    } catch { return false }
}

print(filesOnly.count)
```

Or in macOS 10.11+, iOS 9.0+ with `hasDirectoryPath`

```
let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: aURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
let filesOnly = directoryContents.filter { !$0.hasDirectoryPath }
print(filesOnly.count)
```

Comment: Shorter: `return (try? url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.isDirectoryKey]))?.isDirectory == false`

Comment: `hasDirectoryPath` recognizes files without file extension as file (I guess the API uses UTI) and if `contentsOfDirectory` returns the URL it clearly exists. @MartinR I had that first but I don't want the confuse the OP too much 

Comment: Maybe I'm overlooking something, but I cannot see how `includingPropertiesForKeys` is being used in Foundation. I don't see it being passed to the [NSURLDirectoryEnumerator](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/5102c1686c66d0a93d5070926c8a35307ccda6eb/Sources/Foundation/FileManager.swift#L1006) class.

Comment: @Dave The resource information is inside the URL, it’s not related to the enumerator.

Comment: @vadian Can you point me to where the `includingPropertiesForKeys` value is actually used then?

Comment: `includingPropertiesForKeys` is actually just a directive to prefetch the values for the specified keys from the URL. Like the example in the answer the `isDirectory` value will be available immediately. This is not relevant for this particular flag but there are metadata which can consume a bunch of time.

Comment: I understand the purpose of the parameter, in the aforelinked Foundation code it appears as though this parameter is discarded. Can you see it being used?

Comment: It's being used in `enumerator(at url)` and `contentsOfDirectory(at url`

Comment: Yes, but `enumerator(at url)` takes 4 parameters and returns an instance of the NSURLDirectoryEnumerator class using only 3 parameters and not using `includingPropertiesForKeys` in the link before.

Comment: As I said *`includingPropertiesForKeys` is actually just a directive to prefetch the values for the specified keys from the URL*. You have to tell the API which values you want to be fetched.

Comment: Yes, this is clear from the documentation. I am referring to the passing of the arguments in the Foundation code here though: [enumerator](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/5102c1686c66d0a93d5070926c8a35307ccda6eb/Sources/Foundation/FileManager.swift#L1005) takes 4 arguments and immediately returns a call to [NSPathDirectoryEnumerator](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/5102c1686c66d0a93d5070926c8a35307ccda6eb/Sources/Foundation/FileManager.swift#L1006) with 3 arguments, `includingPropertiesForKeys` is not included. Where is it actually used?

Comment: Of course not, it's not an *output* parameter, the requested information is ***inside*** the enumerated URLs and can be read with `resourceValues(forKeys`.

Comment: Yes, but _where_ in Foundation is `includingPropertiesForKeys` actually being used when `contentsOfDirectory` is called? I can see `keys` value being passed [elsewhere](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/eec4b26deee34edb7664ddd9c1222492a399d122/Darwin/Foundation-swiftoverlay/FileManager.swift#L48) in Foundation, but not for `contentsOfDirectory`.

Comment: You don't understand. You tell `contentsOfDirectory` *Please prefetch the value for the file size at the given URL* (which can take some time) by specifying `includingPropertiesForKeys: [.fileSize]`. Later in the loop to iterate the enumerated URLs you call `let resourceValues = try url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.fileSize])` and you get the value at once with `let fileSize = resourceValues.fileSize!`. That's the goal of `includingPropertiesForKeys`. Of course you can omit the parameter and  retrieve the value directly but this is less efficient with regard to performance.

Comment: I understand the goal of `includingPropertiesForKeys`, it's documented and your explanations appear consistent with this. The _only_ question I have is about the implementation in the Foundation [FileManager](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/5102c1686c66d0a93d5070926c8a35307ccda6eb/Sources/Foundation/FileManager.swift) class and how the `includingPropertiesForKeys` variable is actually used.

Answer (score -1):

I consider:

```
var urls = try! FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: localDocumentsURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
urls = urls.filter { $0.isFileURL }
```

a good enough solution for iOS, in cases, where the app controls what is stored in the app-related sandbox-directories.